# Restricting screen compatibility on Android

Tags: android, android-manifest

The proper way of restricting the installation of an Android app to handheld devices should be to use the `compatible-screen` element in your manifest (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html).

This, however, does not actually work (or not anymore ?).

If my understanding of this documentation is correct, then Google Play should declare my application incompatible with any tablet devices:

```
<compatible-screen>
    <screen android:screenDensity="ldpi" android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="small" />
</compatible-screen>
```

Yet this is not what happens. After an update, and several days of waiting, Google Play keeps declaring the application as compatible with all my devices (tablets included).

Is there a misunderstanding, or is the documentation not up to date ?

Comment: Interesting. The documentation used to say that `<compatible-screens>` was ignored by the Play Store. However, [they seem to say it should be honored now](https://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html#manifest-filters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you declaring it as a direct child of the `<manifest>` element in **AndroidManifest.xml**?

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="640" />

    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="640" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Don't forget to add `xxhdpi` and `xxxhdpi`.

Comment: Oh shit... I see what I did there, it wasn't obvious till I had the two pieces of code side to side... I wrote `compatible-screen` instead of `compatible-screens`... if only there was a way of testing this before sending it to the store... thanks for the help !

Comment: Funny. I haven't noticed the missing "s" before. Glad to help.